# How to convert SQL Server query to U-SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, u-sql, azure-stream-analytics

Can we achieve the below query in u-SQL ?

Sample SQL Server query:

```sql
    Select id,name,date from  users as main left outer join
                           (select distinct id, name, date
                                   from subusers as q
                                   where (date =
                                                 (select max(date) as expr1 from subusers
                                                   where (id = q.id)
                                                 )
                                          )
                            ) as details on main.id = details.id
```

SO far i have made this attempt but getting syntax error:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT id,name,date FROM @searchlog1 AS main LEFT OUTER JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT id, name, date
              FROM @searchlog2 AS dtl WHERE dtl.date == (SELECT MAX(date) AS expr1 FROM @searchlog2 AS a 
WHERE a.id == dtl.id)) AS details ON main.id == details.id

ERROR:
AGG ALL AND ARRAY BETWEEN BIGINT BIT BINARY BY COLUMNSET CREATED CSHARP CURRENT DATETIME DATETIME2 DECIMAL DISTINCT EXISTS FILE FLOAT FOLLOWING GROUP IN INT IS LENGTH LCID MAP MAX MODIFIED MONEY NULL NVARCHAR OR OVER PARTITION PRECEDING REAL SMALLINT SQL STRUCT TINYINT UNBOUNDED UNIQUEIDENTIFIER VARBINARY VARCHAR WITHIN string-literal numeric-literal character-literal punctuation-mark identifier quoted-identifier reserved-identifier variable system-variable expression-end '[' ']' '(' '{' '}' '=' '.' '*' ':' '?' '<' '>' ANTISEMIJOIN AS ASC BROADCASTLEFT BROADCASTRIGHT CROSS DESC EXCEPT FETCH FROM FULL FULLCROSS HASH HAVING INDEXLOOKUP INNER INTERSECT JOIN LEFT LOOP MERGE OFFSET ON OPTION ORDER OUTER OUTER UNION PAIR PIVOT PRODUCE READONLY REQUIRED RIGHT SAMPLE SEMIJO
```

Comment: What attempts did you make so far, anything to share?

Comment: @PeterBons  can you pls check my question as i have edited that

Comment: You are missing a FROM here: `SELECT DISTINCT id,name,date {FROM} LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @PeterBons  inspite of adding that from clause, i am still getting error

Comment: Can you share the full error details? It should include a line number and part of the statement

Comment: @PeterBons Can you pls convert that query in u-sql query ?

Comment: Sample data and expected results really help with this type of question. Thanks

Comment: @wBob Can we convert this query irrespective of result in U-SQL ?

Comment: Look, there are number of issues: the SQL query you have provided does not parse correctly.  You have **not** provided sample data or DDL so it's hard to guess.  What is supposed to be the unique identifier in your tables?  Are there multiple records for the same user id in both the user and subuser table?  Are there records in subuser that are not in user (why the `LEFT JOIN`?)  You could get the same result by just doing `select distinct * from user` so what is the second query adding?  People need the DDL, sample data and expected results in order to answer your question effectively.